# Keras (Tensorflow backend) - Flatten all gradients in an MLP to a tensor of rank 1 (i.e. 1D array)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, gradient

Suppose the following Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Obviously we can calculate the gradients by:

```
grads = K.gradients(loss, params)
```

which just calls:

```
tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
```

This returns **a list** of tensors containing:

1. a tensor with 512x784 elements (gradients of input to hidden connections)
2. a tensor with the gradients of the biases of the 512 units in the hidden layer
3. a tensor with 10x512 elements (gradients of hidden to output connections)
4. a tensor with the gradients of the biases of the 10 output units

I would like to ask if there's a simple way to "flatten" all grads to a single tensor of rank 1 (i.e. 1D array) with (512x784)+512+(10x512)+10 elements, without looping over the layers and corresponding biases.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [backend](https://keras.io/backend/) functions.

```
#flatten the tensors
flattenedList = [K.flatten(x) for x in grads]

#concatenate them
concatenated = K.concatenate(flattenedList)
```

Comment: Ok :) -- Would you mark it as a correct answer then?

Comment: Yes, I just did